# Apple store demands audio permissions in {mediaType: 'photo'}

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'm using only photo mode but from spring 2019 apple store demands permission for micro.
It will be very confusing for user to grant permissions for micro when he is using only photo.
Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Check out your libraries. Because  any of them may need microphone that's why the permission is needed

Comment: I'm pretty sure that problem is in this library. Because app doesn't use camera anywhere else.

Comment: Then just add it into info.plist. It will do no harm

Comment: Isn't it confusing to grant access to mic when you are taking photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The microphone permissions probably would be demanded because from mediaType 'Photo' the user could access to the video recorder witch could record audio too ( a video is a mix of photo and audio ).

Comment: I thought that with type photo user can only take photo but not video.

Comment: Probably there exists a shortcut to access to video when you open that feature, test if you can do it, probably leaving pressed the shot button where you take a photo.
Sorry my poor english.

Comment: Sounds possible.

Comment: Test it, if it is able, you have found the reason!